# Load UITableViewController inside UIViewController inside an UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, subview

I have a UINavigationController that loads its root view controller which is a UIViewController (green color).

That UIViewController has a UISegmentedControl in the navigation bar. It has two segments, "News" and "Program". By default News is selected.

News and Program has their own UITableViewController. When clicking on Program (red) I want to load a subview in the UIViewController with ProgramViewController. The same would happen with NewsViewController (blue).

[image: NewsViewController]
[image: ProgramViewController]

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried that didn't work? What are you expecting?

Comment: How to load another UITableViewController inside the UIViewController, which is already inside a UINavigationController.

I've tried with programmatically initiate the view controllers and adding it to the subview, which loads the view, but not the subclassed tableview cells for each of the UITableViewControllers.

Comment: Use a UITabBarController and hide the tab bar itself.

Comment: @David Do you have any good examples of that?

Answer (score 0):

Load both of them and swap between them either bei adding and removing the related subviews or by hiding and unhiding the one on top.

BTW, there is nothing wrong with using individual table view controllers for both tables, but there is no need for doing so either. You could, if you want, feed both tables from the single view controller that holds the green view.

Comment: I've tried `[self.view addSubview:viewController.view]` but this doesn't load the custom subclassed cells.

Also, I know I could put it all in one view controller, but the code will be too messy.